# How do you enable HTTPS in Jetbrains Upsource 2.0

Tags: ssl, https, upsource

I'm evaluating Upsource, Jetbrain's source code review tool.

There is nothing in the docs or in the 2.0 distribution (that I can find) explaining how to enable SSL/TLS. How can this be done? We can't serve up source code except over HTTPS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has changed for Upsource 2018; it has [built-in TLS support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/configuring-tls.html):

> There are several ways to set up an encrypted HTTPS connection with TLS(SSL) between your Upsource server and its clients.
>
> - Use Upsource's built-in TLS. You can configure Upsource to run in the HTTPS mode:
>
>   - from Configuration Wizard, during the initial Upsource installation or upgrade
>   - from the command line, enabling (and disabling as well) HTTPS for your existing Upsource installation
> - Use a third-party TLS-terminating proxy server. This option is preferable when you have to run Upsource behind a proxy server for other reasons than encryption. See Proxy configuration for details.
>
> You can switch from a third-party TLS-terminating proxy to the Upsource built-in TLS and vice-versa at any time regardless of your current settings.

Answer (score 0):

Make as described in the instructions https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/help/2.0/proxy_configuration.html

Set to Upsource Nginx as a proxy
Close the firewall port 1111, leaving only Nginx watch out.

Configure base url:

```
<upsource_home>\bin\upsource.bat configure --listen-port 1111 --base-url https://upsource.mydomain.com/
```

Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

         ssl_certificate <path_to_certificate>
         ssl_certificate_key <path_to_key>

         server_name  localhost;

         location  / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            # to proxy WebSockets in nginx
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://localhost:1111/;
         }
       }
```